# Switching font and background color on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, beginner

I am currently building a web app where I need to randomly switch the font and color of a title (inside the `#content` div) **and** the background of the page every time a button is clicked.

I wrote the following code that works perfectly, but I'm wondering if it could be optimized (or at least written in a more elegant way).

```
// Switch font randomly
var font = ["lobster", "shadows", "oswald", "josefin", "gloria", "pacifico"];
var color = ["blue", "purple", "yellow", "red", "orange", "green"];
var background = ["bg-blue", "bg-purple", "bg-yellow", "bg-red", "bg-orange", "bg-green"];

$("#try-me").click(function() {
    $("#content")
        .hide()
        .removeClass()
        .addClass(font[Math.floor(Math.random()*font.length)]) // Font
        .addClass(color[Math.floor(Math.random()*color.length)]) // Color
        .fadeIn(600);

    $("html")
        .removeClass()
        .addClass(background[Math.floor(Math.random()*background.length)]); // Background
});
```

Comment: It's pretty clear and elegant as it is.

Comment: I agree with Carlos, looks clear and elegant as it is.

Comment: Perhaps you should ensure that the randomly chosen background and foreground colours are different from each other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The repetition of getting a random font, color, background class cries to be extracted to a utility function:

```
function pickRandom(arr) { 
    return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
}

$("#try-me").click(function() {
    $("#content")
        .hide()
        .removeClass()
        .addClass(pickRandom(font))
        .addClass(pickRandom(color))
        .fadeIn(600);

    $("html")
        .removeClass()
        .addClass(pickRandom(background));
});
```

I also agree with [@MainMa](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/11074/mainma) about defining `background` in terms of `color`.

Other than that, I think it's nice code!

#### Ensuring change

If you want to make sure that each font/color/background are different every time the user clicks on the button, then perhaps you can create another helper:

```
function pickRandomExcept(arr, previous) { 
    while (true) {
        var pick = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
        if (pick != previous) {
            return pick;
        }
    }
}
```

However, in the caller you will need to keep track of the previous picks of each. For example:

```
var picked_color;

$("#try-me").click(function() {
    picked_color = pickRandomExcept(color, picked_color);
    $("#content")
        .hide()
        .removeClass()
        .addClass(pickRandom(font))
        .addClass(picked_color)
        .fadeIn(600);
```

Answer (score 3):

One possible improvement consists of removing code duplication between those two arrays:

```
var color = ["blue", "purple", "yellow", "red", "orange", "green"];
var background = ["bg-blue", "bg-purple", "bg-yellow", "bg-red", "bg-orange", "bg-green"];
```

Instead, you can build the second array from the first one:

```
var color = ["blue", "purple", "yellow", "red", "orange", "green"];
var background = color.map(function (c) { return "bg-" + c; })
```

This has two benefits:

- If colors change, you have to do the change only once.
- If the source of colors change (for example you start loading colors from a database or a configuration file), you have to change only the first line.

On the other hand, the drawbacks are:

- That the code may be more difficult to understand by the beginners.
- That in your particular case, the duplication is not an important issue: there are only six colors and arrays are easily modifiable by hand.

Comment: Nice. You could also just prepend the "bg-" when adding the class, i.e. `addClass('bg-' + ...)`, instead of mapping the array upfront. The benefit would be IE 6/7/8 support, since they don't have `map`

Answer (score 0):

Well code look good, any changes will be just a over thinking. one thing I want to make here is to specify variable for that calculation.this will make a bit readable ( not a very big point though)

```
// Switch font randomly
var font = ["lobster", "shadows", "oswald", "josefin", "gloria", "pacifico"];
var color = ["blue", "purple", "yellow", "red", "orange", "green"];
var background = ["bg-blue", "bg-purple", "bg-yellow", "bg-red", "bg-orange", "bg-green"];

$("#try-me").click(function() {
var selectedFontClass=font[Math.floor(Math.random()*font.length)];
var selectedColorClass=color[Math.floor(Math.random()*color.length)];
var selectedBackgroundClass=background[Math.floor(Math.random()*background.length)];
$("#content")
    .hide()
    .removeClass()
    .addClass(selectedFontClass) // Font
    .addClass(selectedColorClass) // Color
    .fadeIn(600);

$("html")
    .removeClass()
    .addClass(selectedBackgroundClass); // Background
});
```

Comment: On a personal note, I find the original version easier to read vs this version with variables (original looks cleaner).